# Advanced usage on Magento column filter getCondition

Tags: magento, filter, grid, conditional-statements

I'm using Magento 1.7 community edition.

I'm overriding Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Text's getCondition() in order to create a more flexible search on some text columns.  I've figured out that if I return a condition like:

```
array(
  array('like' => '%keyword1%'),
  array('like' => '%keyword2%'),
  ...
)
```

That I can get a filter like:

```
column like '%keyword1%' OR column like '%keyword2%' OR ...
```

But, I need a filter like:

```
column like '%keyword1%' AND column like '%keyword2%' AND ...
```

How would I accomplish that?